# Flush DNS/ network restart Commands using c#

Tags: c#, command-prompt, netsh

For network flush, i usually open command prompt on admin rights and type these commands:

```
netsh winsock reset
netsh int ip reset
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
ipconfig /flushdns
```

I need to run these five commands in c# code

Right now i have a code for only release and renew which works. Below is the code of that.

```
public bool FlushAllNetworks()
        {
            try
            {
                ManagementClass objMC = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
                ManagementObjectCollection objMOC = objMC.GetInstances();
                foreach (ManagementObject objMO in objMOC)
                {
                    //Need to determine which adapter here with some kind of if() statement
                    objMO.InvokeMethod("ReleaseDHCPLease", null, null);
                    objMO.InvokeMethod("RenewDHCPLease", null, null);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: I found an answer. I took the suggestion from AmirHossein and made a small correction. Below is the solution for my own question.

```
        Process process = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        startInfo.Verb = "runas";
        startInfo.Arguments = "/C netsh winsock reset & netsh int ip reset & ipconfig /release & ipconfig /renew & ipconfig /flushdns";
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
```

Comment: You can invoke command line to run these commands

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `Process()` to run commands you mentioned:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.startInfo.FileName = "cmd";
p.startInfo.Arguments = "netsh winsock reset && netsh int ip reset && ipconfig /release && ipconfig /renew && ipconfig /flushdns";

p.Start();
```

It executes the commands in background.

Comment: Thanks. This works. Small correction i have made. I have edited in my question. Thanks a lot though.